# Replication Error when adding small table as new article

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

I have just added a small (200 row) table to my current replication which has now broken my entire replication scenario as it seems to have broken the Log reader. The 2 tables are unrelated.

I am attempting to locate the table the related field is in and drop this table to see if that resolves the issue. Any other help in the meantime would be appreciated if anyone has come across this issue.

The errors I'm getting are:

> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'QUEEN'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20011)
>
> Could not locate text information records for the column "MergeUpdateDesc", ID 28 during command construction. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18773)
>
> The Log-Scan Process failed to construct a replicated command from log sequence number (LSN) {0022f069:000090cb:0026}. Back up the publication database and contact Customer Support Services. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 18805)
>
> The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'QUEEN'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL22037)

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug with Replicating BLOBS in transactional replication. when the snapshot agent ran, something updated the BLOBs currently in the publication and this broke ALL replication streams.

After removing the initial table from the publication it moved onto another table containing BLOB data.

To resolve this I separated all tables containing BLOB data into their own Publication and removed them from my main publication. The Log Reader Agent then kicked back in.

Comment: For future visitors: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2655789